# getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

why when i write

```
document.getElementByClass('home1').setAttribute('style', 'background-image:url(img/red_menu.PNG);');
```

it doesn't work?
i have the element with `class="home1"`

with `document.getElementById('home1')...`
works fine
thanks

Comment: Re your edit, you must have been doing that while I was editing my answer to warn you that it returns a NodeList, not an element (since it can match multiple elements!). If you read the linked documentation you'll have a better idea what it does. Also, again, if you're using IE, it's not going to work, full stop.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder ok, thanks. i'll read it, but can you now say me why it can't setattribue of all NodeList?

Comment: Because the DOM doesn't define that sort of meta-operation (allowing you to call a function on a list and applying that to every element of the list). I think you'll like jQuery, it does that sort of meta-operation. Worth taking a look.

Comment: You also should not use `setAttribute` on HTML documents: it fails for many attributes in IE6-7, including style. Use the DOM Level 2 HTML/CSS properties directly, it is more readable as well as more reliable. `element.style.backgroundImage= 'url(img/red_menu.PNG)';`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClass`; [details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). Note that IE does [not support this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(VS.85).aspx#custom) (yet).

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList of matching elements (rather than a single element), so:

```
var list, index;
list = document.getElementsByClassName("home1");
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].setAttribute(/* ... */);
}
```

For this sort of thing, you may want to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), etc., to pave over the various browser differences for you. They can save you a *lot* of time and trouble compared with dealing with those differences yourself.

For instance, in jQuery:

```
$(".home1").attr(/* ... */);
```

...applies that attribute (via [`jQuery#attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) to every element with the class "home1". Although in your particular case, you'd probably want [`jQuery#css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you have only one classname in your entire HTML file, then you could also use

```js
  document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-nav')[0].setAttribute('id', 'navbar-toggle');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

> document.getElementsByClassName('home1')[0].setAttribute('style',
> 'background-image:url(img/red_menu.PNG);');