# Setting the name attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565909/getelementbyclass-setattribute-doesnt-work)

Why this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cke_source').setAttribute('name', "mymessage")
```

Is returning:

```
TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'setAttribute'
```

`document.getElementsByClassName('cke_source')` is returning the object correctly.

- No jQuery please.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('cke_source'));` PS: according to the error message you get `NodeList`, not a node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return a node list (like an array) of elements. So, you need to treat it like an array. Try this if you only have one element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cke_source')[0].setAttribute('name', "mymessage")
```

Answer (score 5):

getElementsByClassName is giving you back a collection of items, not a single item.

```
var pColl = document.getElementsByClassName('cke_source');
for (var ii=0; ii< pColl.length; ii++)
{
    pColl[ii].setAttribute('name', 'foo');
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousty. Why `ii` and not `i` as variable ? Is it a convention anywhere or anything in particular ?

Comment: It is a convention that a lot of people use.  The thinking is that when you need to trace through code... doing a search for 'i' is pretty useless.  : )

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted