# add class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

I am writing some vanilla JavaScript to create a nice navigation menu.  I am stuck on adding an active class.

I am getting elements by class name NOT by id. The below code works if substituted with id, however, I need it to apply to more than one element.

HTML

```
<img class="navButton" id="topArrow" src="images/arrows/top.png" />
<img class="navButton" id="rightArrow" src="images/arrows/right.png" />
```

JS

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");

button.onmouseover = function() {
    button.setAttribute("class", "active");
    button.setAttribute("src", "images/arrows/top_o.png");
}
```

No answers containing jQuery please.

Comment: duplicate of [getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565909/getelementbyclass-setattribute-doesnt-work) and [getElementsByClassName onclick issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667533/getelementsbyclassname-onclick-issue)

Comment: Sidenote, if you want to target IE8 then document.getElementsByClassName is not available, but document.querySelectorAll is. They both return a NodeList. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Oof, my memory was a bit off, getElementsByClassName apparently returns a HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a node list. So you'll have to iterate over the list and bind the event to individual elements. Like this...

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    buttons[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.setAttribute("class", "active");
        this.setAttribute("src", "images/arrows/top_o.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good solution...will let you know how I get on with it.

Comment: @vincentieo: Please, if the client moves the mouse over all buttons, they'll all show the same picture, and they'll all have the `active` class. You're attaching tons of event listeners all over the place, and if ever you're going to add a new navigation element using ajax, this won't work. Honestly: _delegate the event_. It's, by far, more efficient, flexible, and most JS-like approach to this problem. Check the fiddle at the bottom of my answer: 1 event listener, no global variables, no non-sense

Comment: @vincentieo: would you be so kind as to explain _why_ you prefer this to delegation? I'm honestly struggeling to make sense of your choice here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem perhaps this solution seems more succint and short, thus easy to understand at first sight for beginners (Such in my case). But I ll give yours a try ;)

Comment: In case if someone else is reading the OP question, you could use .classList.add("active");  and to remove you do the opposite.  .remove("active");

Answer (score 7):

In your snippet, `button` is an instance of `NodeList`, to which you can't attach an event listener directly, nor can you change the elements' `className` properties directly.
Your best bet is to delegate the event:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img' && target.className.match(/\bnavButton\b/))
    {
        target.className += ' active';//set class
    }
},false);
```

Of course, my guess is that the `active` class needs to be removed once the `mouseout` event fires, you might consider using a second delegator for that, but you *could* just aswell attach an event handler to the one element that has the `active` class:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var oldSrc, target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img' && target.className.match(/\bnavButton\b/))
    {
        target.className += ' active';//set class
        oldSrc = target.getAttribute('src');
        target.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrows/top_o.png');
        target.onmouseout = function()
        {
            target.onmouseout = null;//remove this event handler, we don't need it anymore
            target.className = target.className.replace(/\bactive\b/,'').trim();
            target.setAttribute('src', oldSrc);
        };
    }
},false);
```

There is some room for improvements, with this code, but I'm not going to have all the fun here ;-).

### [Check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EzmWL/)

Comment: how to use it for document ready instead of mouseover listener case?

Comment: @YannisDran: either use `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){ if (document.readyState === 'complete') console.log('ready');}, false);` or, which is what I think you actually want: `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ console.log('window loaded');}, false);` Both work equally well. Also check [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures), which explains why you'd want to use an event listener for `window.onload` instead of binding a handler directly...

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I wanted add a class and I tried to find how I could attach a document ready event so that the rest of the code would be executed correctly. Check my relevant question to understand what I meant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319503/select-and-add-class-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method adapted from Jquery 2.1.1 that take a dom element instead of a jquery object (so jquery is not needed). Includes type checks and regex expressions:

```
function addClass(element, value) {
    // Regex terms
    var rclass = /[\t\r\n\f]/g,
        rnotwhite = (/\S+/g);

    var classes,
        cur,
        curClass,
        finalValue,
        proceed = typeof value === "string" && value;

    if (!proceed) return element;

    classes = (value || "").match(rnotwhite) || [];

    cur = element.nodeType === 1
        && (element.className
                ? (" " + element.className + " ").replace(rclass, " ")
                : " "
        );

    if (!cur) return element;

    var j = 0;

    while ((curClass = classes[j++])) {

        if (cur.indexOf(" " + curClass + " ") < 0) {

            cur += curClass + " ";

        }

    }

    // only assign if different to avoid unneeded rendering.
    finalValue = cur.trim();

    if (element.className !== finalValue) {

        element.className = finalValue;

    }

    return element;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns HTMLCollection so you could try this

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton")[0];
```

**Edit**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");
for(i=0;buttons.length;i++){
   buttons[i].onmouseover = function(){
     this.className += ' active' //add class
     this.setAttribute("src", "images/arrows/top_o.png");
   }
}
```

Comment: NodeList, not an array.

Comment: @ArdaChapuler: OP needs to add the class to _all_ elements in the list, not just the first

Comment: That works for the first image but not for the second (or third or forth).  Is there some kind of wildcard to be used?  I cant believe that there is no way to add a class to an element, on mouse over, according to elements in a class.  

Perhaps I get an containing div id and look for elements inside it to add class?

Comment: do you want to add class or set class?

Comment: @vincentieo: That's because `button` is being assigned a reference to the first element, and no other. The suggestion to solve this with a loop is attaching tons of event listeners, which is wasteful. Check my answer, which uses but 1 listener to delegate the event...

Comment: yup.. +1 to Elias' answer. His solution is better.

Comment: @ArdaChapuler: Thanks for the +1. You wouldn't happen to know why the OP _isn't_ going for delegation, but is binding all events individually? The way the accepted answer looks, you just _know_ what the next question is going to be: _"How can I restore the `src` attribute, and how can I _unset_ the `active` class?"_ or something... I just don't get it why he's not using delegation...

Comment: people likes quick and dirty ways :)

Answer (score 0):

There is build in forEach loop for array in ECMAScript 5th Edition.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons,function(button) { 
    button.setAttribute("class", "active");
    button.setAttribute("src", "images/arrows/top_o.png"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a custom "foreach" function of sorts for these kinds of things:

```
function Each( objs, func )
{
    if ( objs.length ) for ( var i = 0, ol = objs.length, v = objs[ 0 ]; i < ol && func( v, i ) !== false; v = objs[ ++i ] );
    else for ( var p in objs ) if ( func( objs[ p ], p ) === false ) break;
}
```

(Can't remember where I found the above function, but it has been quite useful.)

Then after fetching your objects (to `elements` in this example) just do

```
Each( elements, function( element )
{
    element.addEventListener( "mouseover", function()
    {
        element.classList.add( "active" );
        //element.setAttribute( "class", "active" );
        element.setAttribute( "src", "newsource" );
    });

    // Remove class and new src after "mouseover" ends, if you wish.
    element.addEventListener( "mouseout", function()
    {
        element.classList.remove( "active" );
        element.setAttribute( "src", "originalsource" );
    });
});
```

[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) is a simple way for handling elements' classes. Just needs a shim for a few browsers. If you must use `setAttribute` you must remember that whatever is set with it **will** overwrite the previous values.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that you need to use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` on some IE versions. Test with `if ( document.addEventListener ) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a class name to the beginning of the funciton and the 2nd and 3rd arguments are optional and the magic is done for you!

```
function getElementsByClass(searchClass, node, tag) {

  var classElements = new Array();

  if (node == null)

    node = document;

  if (tag == null)

    tag = '*';

  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);

  var elsLen = els.length;

  var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\\\s)' + searchClass + '(\\\\s|$)');

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {

    if (pattern.test(els[i].className)) {

      classElements[j] = els[i];

      j++;

    }

  }

  return classElements;

}
```