# Select and add class in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

Cross Platform if possible, how can I select classes in Javascript (but not Jquery please -MooTools is fine though-) on code that I can't add an ID?
Specifically, I want to add the class "cf" on any li below:

HTML

```
<div class="itemRelated">
  <ul>
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="even">
```

I tried to fiddle it but something is missing:

Javascript

```
 var list, i;
list = document.getElementsByClassName("even, odd");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[index].setAttribute('class', 'cf');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7BY8/1/)

ps. This question phenomenally has possible [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944843/add-class-with-javascript), (another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944843/add-class-with-javascript)) but none of the answers makes it clear.

Comment: Interested in compilance in particular IE version?

Comment: not exactly a particular IE version, just to support modern browsers and the *best possible* combination of old IE versions. I wouldn't mind if IE6 or IE7 are out of question for example, but if there's something usable, I would take it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Using plain javascript:

```
var list;
list = document.querySelectorAll("li.even, li.odd");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
   list[i].classList.add('cf');
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkuAT/)

**For older browsers you could use this:**

```
var list = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].className == "even" || elements[i].className == "odd") {
        list.push(elements[i]);
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    if (list[i].className.split(' ').indexOf('cf') < 0) {
        list[i].className = list[i].className + ' cf';
    }
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6cCf/1/)

---

### Using Mootools:

```
$$('.itemRelated li').addClass('cf');
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4L5w/)

**or if you want to target specific by Class:**

```
$$('li.even, li.odd').addClass('cf');
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4L5w/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Just to learn, what about if I want to add a second class just for li.odd?  I tried this $$('li.even, li.odd").addClass('cf','sec'); but didn't seem to work.

Comment: @YannisDran, then you can separate them with a space. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4L5w/2/

Comment: adding classes with `.addClass()` and space is not a great idea - works because the code does not check the arg passed but caused classList change to be rejected - see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/commit/bd6ac113600fa508017c29237cf03c36171e9603#commitcomment-4656198 - see how this can have an adverse effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/3EyzL/. `addClass` should not duplicate classes, adding space removes that safety.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, thanks for the warning/correction ! Is `element.addClass('bar').addClass('foo');` the best solution then?

Comment: as it stands in the current implementation, spaces will work fine - so as long as you are certain neither of the two classes are already on the element, use it. otherwise, chain two like you said. also see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZJacl2VkKo - depends on the usecase and so on.

Comment: @YannisDran, please read good input from Dimitar in the comments here.

Comment: Nice question Yannis! And great answer @Sergio ! Its very helpful.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is old, but is there any reason not to simply do this (besides potential browser support issues)?

```
document.querySelectorAll("li.even, li.odd").forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add('cf');
});
```

Support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5

Answer (score 3):

As others mention for selecting the elements you should use `.querySelectorAll()` method. DOM  also provides [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) API which supports adding, removing and toggling classes:

```
var list, i;
list = document.querySelectorAll('.even, .foo');
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].classList.add('cf');
}
```

As always IE9 and bellow don't support the API, if you want to support those browsers you can use a shim, MDN has [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Answer (score 3):

Using some newer browser objects and methods.

**Pure JS:**
Details: old fashioned way, declaring stuff at the beginging than iterating in one big loop over elements with index 'i', no big science here. One thing is using `classList` object which is a smart way to add/remove/check classes inside arrays.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.even','.odd'),
    i, length;

for(i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add('cf');
}
```

**Pure JS - 2:**
Details: document.querySelectorAll returns an array-like object which can be accessed via indexes but has no Array methods. Calling slice from Array.prototype returns an array of fetched elements instantly (probably the fastest NodeList -> Array conversion). Than you can use a `.forEach` method on newly created array object.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.even','.odd'))
 .forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.add('cf');
});
```

**Pure JS - 3:**
Details: this is quite similar to v2, `[].map` is roughly that same as `Array.prototype.map` except here you declare an empty array to call the map method. It's shorter but more (ok little more) memory consuming. `.map` method runs a function on every element from the array and returns a new array (adding return in inside function would cause filling the returned values, here it's unused).

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.even','.odd'), function(element) {
    element.classList.add('cf');
});
```

Pick one and use ;)

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` is supported in IE8, `getElementsByClassName` is not, which does not get two classes at the same time either. None of them work in iE7, but who cares.

Then it's  just a matter of iterating and adding to the `className` property.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".even, .odd");
for (var i = list.length; i--;) {
    list[i].className = list[i].className + ' cf';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7BY8/2/)

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want to select elements with different classes all together then the best choice is querySelectorAll.

`querySelectorAll` uses CSS selectors to select elements. As we add the same CSS properties to different elements by separating them by a comma in the same way we can select those elements using this.

```css
.even, .odd {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Both elements with class 'even' and 'odd' get bold.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.even, .odd');
```

Now, both the elements are selected.

**+Point**: you should use `classList.add()` method to add class.

Here is the complete code for you.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.even, .odd');

for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].classList.add('cf');
}
```

Comment: list.classList.add('cf'); will never work ..