# Want to add / remove classes in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite the jQuery code below in pure JavaScript to save loading time.

[Here is the link to the demo page](http://emsons.iqsmarthomes.in).

```
var playstate = function (){
    $(".magicwand").addClass("logo-effect");
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".magicwand").removeClass("logo-effect");
        }, 6000);
}
playstate();
setInterval(playstate, 6100);
```

Comment: Depends on your browser support.  The closest analog to the jQuery selector engine would be [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).  Adding and removing classes would be achieved with the [`classList` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).  If you need to support older browsers, you'll need to use different means of traversing/selecting in the DOM.

Comment: You might just check [Plain JS](https://plainjs.com/javascript/) site for what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add class with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944843/add-class-with-javascript)

Comment: @Avinash Deshmukh : Your given demo link is not opening somehow, but i have posted my answer on my own prediction , let me know.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati Thanks mate! But the code you have suggested does not work. Please check the link (have modified).

Comment: I have just did what seems like as you were want Man not exact what your needs, as at that time your link was not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have converted your jquery code to pure javascript.

```js
var playstate = function() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("magicwand");
  element[0].classList.add("logo-effect");
  setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("magicwand");
    element[0].classList.remove("logo-effect");
  }, 6000);
}
playstate();
setInterval(playstate, 6100);
```

```html
<div class="magicwand">test</div>
```

Comment: I have just guide you like how to convert jquery function in pure js.

Comment: I am looking at the guide as  we speak. Thanks @JigarPrajapati