# justify - Best approach

Tags: javascript, justify

webkit browser is not supported "ruby of justify".

I found this javascript (https://code.google.com/p/justify/).

As a result of using this, a new problem has occurred...

```
 <ul id="list">
  <li>
   <h3 id="main"><ruby>Lorem<rt id="sub">Ipsum</rt></ruby></h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...... </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

This is fine. But this script used "document.getElementById".

When the element is increased, of course, it does not work.

When I rewrite "document.getElementById" to "document.getElementsByClass", `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method`...

When the element is increased, what I do I do?

(Sorry... I'm not good at English)

Comment: What do yo mean by element is increased? do you mean you have more than one `<rt id="sub"`?

Comment: I think you mean `document.getElementsByClassName`...

Comment: Please show us your javascript code that throws this error! Else I can only guess that you've got the same problem as in [getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565909/getelementbyclass-setattribute-doesnt-work).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I relearn from English... Maybe I understand that Is not being captured in dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method...
> ```

This error occurs because you are trying to treat a list of nodes like a single node.  Probably because you are forgetting to get an element out of the result of `getElementsByClassName`.

`getElementById` returns a single DOM element, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a list (array-like object) of DOM elements.  You have to index into the latter, but not the former.

```
<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>

<script>
alert(
    document.getElementById('bar')   // One result at most, so no [0].
    ===
    // ClassName, not Class.  [0] since the result is a list.
    document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0]
);
</script>
```

should alert "true"