# Dynamically change href and link to a url fragment

Tags: javascript, html, href, document-ready

Hope someone can help.
I'm trying to dynamically change hrefs on a page and then point the user to a url which includes a fragment as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.pathname.indexOf('cab2') > -1){
        document.getElementsByClassName('resourceLink').setAttribute('href','http://www.myserver.net/cab2/#linkResources');
        } else {
            document.getElementByClassName('resourceLink').setAttribute('href','http://www.myserver.net/cab/#linkResources');
        };
});
```

In the HTML I'm using several links like this:

```
<a class="resourceLink" href="" title="Link to Resources section" target="_blank">Resources</a>
```

What I was hoping for was the script would check what url the visitor had used to arrive at the site, either

- http://www.myserver.net/cab/ or,
- http://www.myserver.net/cab2/ and then set the appropriate hrefs to either:
- http://www.myserver.net/cab/#linkResources or,
- http://www.myserver.net/cab2/#linkResources

What happens though is the link opens up the base page (www.myserver.net/cab or cab2) and not the #fragment page.

What am I doing wrong? 
My thanks for your interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565909/getelementbyclass-setattribute-doesnt-work)

Comment: You are using jQuery, use it.

Answer (score 3):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element. You can use `.each()` to iterate all `.resourceLink` elements, `.attr()` to set `href` attribute value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var link =  document.location.pathname.indexOf('cab2') > -1 ? "cab2" : "cab";
    $('.resourceLink')
    .each(function() {
       $(this)
       .attr('href','http://www.myserver.net/'+ link +'#linkResources')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @guest271314, still can't get it to work though but your comment has got me started. Note you've got a minor typo in your var link statement, an extra closing bracket.

Comment: @RogerW _"still can't get it to work"_ What is current issue? Is last forward slash `/` necessary?

Comment: Yep, it is still loading the base page - www.myserver.net/cab/ (or cab2) and not the appended fragment i.e. www.myserver.net/cab/#linkResources. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your updates @guest271314 but it still isn't working. Might this be anything to do with the fact that I'm calling this from a div on the main page (index.html) which then loads a new html page into index.html and unhides it's content i.e. the page that this code is on is actually on about.html which has been loaded into index.html.

Comment: Thanks @guest271314, not sure I'm up to http://plnkr.co/ but I can show you it in action. Load http://www.rogw.net/cab2/ then click the 'About' tab, the first 3 links on that page to the Resources tab should open a new window with the url www.rogw.net/cab2/#linkResources. If you type www.rogw.net/cab2/#linkResources directly into your browser it opens as it should.

Comment: @RogerW `javascript` at Answer does not appear at link? You should be able to reproduce issue at plnkr

Comment: Thanks again @guest271314. Think you might have got me going in the right direction. I have my question's javascript (sorry, your proposed solution) embedded within about.html, I think I need to migrate it to the existing js file (js-tabs.js) I'm using to display the tab items within index.html and then make a call to it from within about.html.